# Dual definition for distributivity lattice conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders, duality-theorems

I am starting discrete mathematics and it came to me that distributive lattices has 2 equicalent representations for their definition:

- $a\wedge (b\vee c) = (a \wedge b)\vee (a\wedge c)$
- $a\vee (b\wedge c) = (a \vee b)\wedge (a\vee c)$

However, I couldn't find proof for this equivalence. I am using "Introduction to discrete structures for computer science and engineering" by Preparata, FRANCO. If you can help me with an insight or at least some place I could research about the matter, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the first formulation, you get
\begin{align}
(a\vee b) \wedge (a\vee c)
&= ((a\vee b)\wedge a) \vee ((a\vee b) \wedge c)\\
&= a \vee ((a \vee b) \wedge c) \tag{absorption}\\
&= a \vee (c \wedge (b \vee a))\\
&= a \vee ((c \wedge b) \vee (c \wedge a)) \tag{first formulation}\\
&= a \vee (a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)\\
&= a \vee (b\wedge c). \tag{absorption}
\end{align}

The converse is analogous.

Comment: Thank you, so much, @amrsa. It's a very elegant proof.